# I am getting dimension mismatch when creating a sequential model in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Whenever I add a flatten layer between dense layers in sequential model or when I add a MaxPooling1D after a flatten layer, I am getting an error which looks like this:

> Input 0 is incompatible with layer : expected ndim=3,
>   found ndim=2

Here are my models where I found these errors:

```
#Model 1
model = Sequential()
from keras.layers import Flatten,Dense,MaxPooling1D
model.add(Flatten(input_shape=(28,28)))
model.add(Dense(256,activation="relu"))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(128,activation="relu"))
model.add(Dense(64,activation="relu"))
model.add(Dense(10,activation="softmax"))

#Model2
model = Sequential()
from keras.layers import Flatten,Dense,MaxPooling1D
model.add(Flatten(input_shape=(28,28)))
model.add(MaxPooling1D(2))
model.add(Dense(256,activation="relu"))
model.add(Dense(128,activation="relu"))
model.add(Dense(64,activation="relu"))
model.add(Dense(10,activation="softmax"))
```

I am using these models to work on fashion MNIST dataset where the input shape is 28X28.

Also, can anyone explain where did I go wrong when I am creating this model?
Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

I hope you are using Keras with Tensorflow as backend. You have to expand dimensions of the image using numpy expand dimension function like

```
import numpy as np


image=np.expand_dims(image,axis=0)
model.predict(image)
```